# Set of all symmetries that maps a hexagon to itself

Tags: group-theory

What is a good way to find the set of all symmetries that maps a hexagon back to itself?

Comment: Rotations and reflections. This group is known as $D_{12}$, the dihedral group of order $12$. It's some times written $D_6$ instead, because for one, it's a hexagon, and secondly, no dihedral group has an odd number of elements, so you might as well divide the indices by $2$.

Comment: I was told this set consists of R0,R180,F,F'. But there should be 12 as I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

To find the set, consider that the symmetry is completely determined by where two adjacent vertices map to. Therefore, you should pick two adjacent vertices on the hexagon, call them $A,B,$ say. There are 6 different places $A$ can move to and for each of those, $B$ can move to one of two different places. Therefore there are 12 symmetries.

The way to write them down as a set is to call the rotation of $A$ (say clockwise) to the next adjacent vertex $\sigma$ and then to call the reflection in the line through the vertex $A$ and the centre of the hexagon $\tau.$ Then you should see that to move $A$ to some other vertex you can either do $\sigma^k$ (repeat $\sigma$ $k$ times) or $\sigma^k\tau$ (do $\tau$ then do $\sigma$ $k$ times) for some integer $k\ge0$. You should be able to determine which other transformations are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Look at $$\begin{cases}|D_6| = 12 \\D_6 = \langle a,b\rangle\\a^6 = e\\b^2 = e \\ba = a^5b \end{cases}$$

where $a =$ rotation of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $b =$ reflection in a line joining the midpoints of two opposite sides.